# Cmake support for tasking tri-core compiler toolchain

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui, cmake-language

This is unsure if cmake support is available for the tasking tri-core compiler toolchain.
We could use a normal makefile to compile using this compiler, but I would like to configure cmake to do the same in windows

Comment: Did you try using your compiler with cmake to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You could either use [Greenhills MULTI](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Green%20Hills%20MULTI.html?highlight=s) project files, or define your own [Toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) to enable cross-compiling for your project.

Answer (score 0):

TASKING toolset support was added in [CMake 2.25](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.25/variable/CMAKE_TASKING_TOOLSET.html). Works fine. For some reason it refuses to support C++ even though the documentation says that `cctc` tools supports it.